# Restriction's base for regex in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm new to XML and wanted to know what will the restriction's base be for these attributes in a XSD file? string, positiveInteger, or decimal?

```
<xs:attribute name="sku" use="required">
   <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
         <xs:pattern value="\d{5}"></xs:pattern>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>

<xs:attribute name="price" use="required">   
   <xs:simpleType> 
      <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
         <xs:pattern value="\d+\.\d{2}"></xs:pattern>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
 </xs:attribute>
```

Comment: What is wrong with the current approach?

Comment: I'm just asking if it's correct.

Comment: Depends on the semantics of sku and price. For me it looks correct in general but I don’t know about the meaning of sku. In worst case you could still fix things and do type conversion on data receiving sides

Comment: sku is like an id which needs to be strictly 5 digits. 

My question is, does the restriction's base need to be a string, or positiveInteger. Similarly the price attribute's base... should it be decimal or string. I ask since I'm using Regex in it, should I be adding the attribute's base based on the pattern in it i.e. a string or based on what the attribute that ie actually is: positiveInteger or decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I tend to be suspicious of attempts to restrict numeric types using regular expressions.

For example, the pattern `\d{5}` suggests that 01234 is legal but 1234 is not. That has some practical problems because many applications outputting an integer are likely to prefer to format it as 1234. It also suggests that 01234 and 1234 are not equivalent, which makes me question whether this is really an integer, or just a string consisting of digits. Does it make sense to add two of these values? If not, I would question whether modelling it as an integer is correct.

(A classic example here is phone numbers, where leading zeros are significant, and addition makes no sense. Modelling phone "numbers" as integers is therefore wrong.)

Similarly, I can see why you might want to require a value to be expressed as 8.10 rather than 8.1, because that's the way money amounts are usually written. But it feels wrong to me: if it's a decimal value, then 8.10 and 8.1 are different ways of writing the same number.